# List of numbers visualization in Python (ValueError: too many values to unpack)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've a list of numbers that I want to visualize in python. However I'm not getting a proper expected output of the visualization. I'm getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from statistics import mean
import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randrange

def takeHalfTest(a,b,oper,order):
    asOrig=np.random.randint(1,7,a) 

    if(order==1): 
        as1=np.sort(asOrig)  
    else:
        as1=-np.sort(-asOrig)
    as1=as1[0:b] 
    out=0 
    if(oper==1):
        out=min(as1) 
    elif(oper==2):
        out=max(as1)
    elif(oper==3):
        out=mean(as1) 
    else:
        diffs=np.diff(as1) 
        dMin=np.min(diffs) 
        j=np.argmin(diffs) 
        if(dMin<0):
            out=j-1
        else:
            out=b
    return out 


results = []
n= 10
m= 300

for a1 in range(1,n-1):
    for b1 in range(1,a1):
        for oper1 in range(1,4):
            for order1 in range(1,2):
                for a2 in range(1,(n-a1)):
                    for b2 in range(1,a2):
                        for oper2 in range(1,4):
                            for order2 in range(1,2):
                                counter1=0
                                counter2=0

                                for i in range(1,300):
                                    res1= takeHalfTest(a1,b1, oper1,order1)
                                    res2= takeHalfTest(a2,b2, oper2,order2)
                                    if res1 < res2:
                                        counter1= counter1+1
                                    if res1 == res2 :
                                        counter2= counter2+1
                                results += [counter1/m]
                                results += [counter2/m]

print(results)
```

and the code for the visualization:

```
ps = results
f,p = plt.hist(ps,100)
f = f / np.trapz(p,f)
plt.plot(p,f)
grid('on')
plt.xlabel('P(procedure)')
plt.ylabel('freq.')
plt.title('Probabilities of diff. procedures')
```

Output
[image: Code Output]

Expected result

[image: Expected Output]

> Error part(Error is here)
> I'm visualizing results, which is a list of 2268 numbers. Here I'm showing 10 items from the list by running visualization code (results2 is the 10 items from the results, Just to show the error. It's giving same error for whole results).

```
 results2 = [0.37333333333333335, 0.21, 0.3233333333333333, 
    0.21666666666666667, 0.42, 0.18666666666666668, 0.2966666666666667, 
    0.23, 0.2633333333333333, 0.24]
ps = results2

f, p, _ = plt.hist(ps,100)
# f,p = plt.hist(ps,100)
f = f / np.trapz(p,f)
plt.plot(p,f)
plt.grid('on')
plt.xlabel('P(procedure)')
plt.ylabel('freq.')
plt.title('Probabilities of diff. procedures')
```

Error Output

[image: Error Output]

Comment: [matplotlib.hist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) returns three values - n, bins, and patches. You have to provide the equivalent number of variables, even if it is a throwaway variable `f, p, _ = plt.hist(ps,100)`

Comment: `f, p, _ = plt.hist(ps,100)` it doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: You still get the same error message? Unlikely, I would say.

Comment: Output is similar with the error message `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (99,) (100,)`

Comment: Obviously, you have one more bin edge than bin values. This is all one can say, as you did not explain in the question what you want to achieve with your code. And the entire first part is irrelevant to your question - provide a sample array instead.

Comment: Well, I've mentioned that I've a list that i want to visualize and also provided the expected look of the visualization.
results is a list and it's length 2268, that's why i added whole code that shows everything. I thought Providing length of 2268 numbers list would be confusing.

Comment: `f, p, _ = plt.hist(ps,100)` line indicates error on this line with the message that i mentioned earlier `f = f / np.trapz(p,f)`

Comment: I've edited the post and mentioned the error specifically as you recommended.